# espresso to wait for activity onDestroy

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-instrumentation

The test is: in `ActivityA`, a button click starts `ActivityB` and closes `ActivityA`. How to test that `ActivityA` has been destroyed?
I've created an `IdlingResource` to check `isFinishing()` or `isDestroyed()`, and also monitored a boolean in a custom `ActivityTestRule`, but it never gets called and times out.

I also tried to check when `ActivityB` gets created using `intended/hasComponent` but if I call right after `perform(click())`, it returns false.

All the animations / transitions are off.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use Espresso to verify that onDestroy is being called. You should be doing higher level tests with Espresso such as testing that clicking a button will launch another activity, or when you enter in bad data and press submit an error shows up and is visible on the screen.

For testing onDestroy I would recommend doing that in a unit test and you can use something like Robolectric for that.

Comment: I've also tried testing that a UI component of `ActivityB` is visible, but it's not consistent. Sometimes it'll fail.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but again, I wouldn't test `onDestroy` with Espresso.